# sys.exit(0) error in Spark 2/Zeppelin

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

When I run

```
sys.exit(0)
```

in Scala/zep 0.7/Spark2/HDP2.6 I get:

```
NotebookServer.java[afterStatusChange]:2055) - Job 20170704-124002_811491340 is finished, status: ERROR, exception: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed), result: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
```

Then I get `connection refused` if I try to do anything Spark2 via Zeppelin.
If I restart Spark2 and Zeppelin, things are OK, and I have done lots of other things no problem.

Is there an alternative way of stopping paragraph execution other than `sys.exit(0)`?

Comment: I also faced similar situation. The best thing I could come up is the kill the executing spark job from the Spark UI. In the Spark UI , stages then kill the executing job.

Comment: Thanks Avishek: good to know it is not just me. If I find anything better I will post it here.